# What good alternatives are there for URL based sharing for .APKs and .AABs?

Tags: android, file-upload, share, android-app-bundle

I have until recently, used https://www.distributeapps.com/ for creating shareable URLs of my APK builds for internal the testers of my team.
However, with the coming of August 1st, we have to switch to App bundles(.aab) for Play Store uploads, etc. Since Distributeapps doesn't have an option for .aab uploads, I was wondering if there are any other alternatives online that can be used for uploading and sharing for personal use only.

Comment: First, what does the data look like? I believe you could do without the loop and if causes. Second, what do you mean by "normal distribution"? What do you want to plot? Do you want to estimate the density like with https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html? Or fit a normal curve?

Comment: you can't plot a normal distribution. you have categorical values. You should plot a histogram. something like this https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html